# FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher with a null pointer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, android-studio, kotlin, okhttp

I am building an android application that is connected to AWS. After I saved the data into the database, it can't be backed up since it gives me null results from the database. The error is: OkHttp fatal Dispatcher, I already installed the dependencies in my Gradle code too.

```
object Backend {


  private const val TAG = "Backend"

fun initialize(applicationContext: Context): Backend {
    try {
        //also added line 14
        Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
        Amplify.addPlugin(AWSApiPlugin())
        Amplify.addPlugin(AWSS3StoragePlugin())

        Amplify.configure(applicationContext)

        Log.i(TAG, "Initialized Amplify")
        } catch (e: AmplifyException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not initialize Amplify", e)
       }
          Log.i(TAG, "Registering hub event")

    Amplify.Hub.subscribe(HubChannel.AUTH) { hubEvent: 
     HubEvent<*> ->

        when (hubEvent.name) {
            InitializationStatus.SUCCEEDED.toString() -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "Amplify successfully initialized")
            }
            InitializationStatus.FAILED.toString() -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "Amplify initialization failed")
            }
            else -> {
                when 
    (AuthChannelEventName.valueOf(hubEvent.name)) {
                    AuthChannelEventName.SIGNED_IN -> {
                        updateUserData(true)
                        Log.i(TAG, "Hub: Signed_in")
                    }
                    AuthChannelEventName.SIGNED_OUT -> {
                        updateUserData(false)
                        Log.i(TAG, "Hub: Signed out")
                    }
                    else -> Log.i(TAG, """HUB EVENT 
:${hubEvent.name}""")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving session status")

    // is user already authentictied (from a previous 
execution)?
    Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
            { result ->
                Log.i(TAG, result.toString())
                val cognitoAuthSession = result as 
AWSCognitoAuthSession
                //Update UI
                
this.updateUserData(cognitoAuthSession.isSignedIn)
                when (cognitoAuthSession.identityId.type) {
                    AuthSessionResult.Type.SUCCESS -> 
Log.i(TAG, "IdentityId : " + 
cognitoAuthSession.identityId.value)
                    AuthSessionResult.Type.FAILURE -> 
Log.i(TAG, "IdentityId not present because: " + 
cognitoAuthSession.identityId.error.toString())
                }

            },

            { error -> Log.i(TAG, error.toString()) }
    )

    return this
 }
 private fun updateUserData(withSignedInStatus: Boolean) {
    UserData.setSignedIn(withSignedInStatus)

    val notes = UserData.notes().value
    val isEmpty = notes?.isEmpty() ?: false
    //query notes when signed in and we do not have notes yet
    if (withSignedInStatus && isEmpty) {

        this.queryNotes()
    } else {
        UserData.resetNotes()
     }
 }

 fun signOut() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Initiate Signout Sequence")

    Amplify.Auth.signOut(
            { Log.i(TAG, "Signed out!") },
            { error -> Log.e(TAG, error.toString()) }

    )
 }

 fun signIn(callingActivity: Activity) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Initiate Signin Sequence")

    Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(
            callingActivity,
            { result: AuthSignInResult -> Log.i(TAG, 
result.toString()) },
            { error: AuthException -> Log.e(TAG, 
error.toString()) }
    )
}

// pass the data from web redirect to Amplify libs
fun handleWebUISignInResponse(requestCode: Int, resultCode: 
Int, data: Intent?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "received requestCode : $requestCode and 
resultCode : $resultCode")
    if (requestCode == 
AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.WEB_UI_SIGN_IN_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
        Amplify.Auth.handleWebUISignInResponse(data)
    }
}

fun queryNotes() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Querying notes")

    Amplify.API.query(
            ModelQuery.list(NoteData::class.java),
            { response ->
                Log.e(TAG, "Queried")
                for (noteData in response.data) {
                   // Log.i(TAG, noteData.name)
                    // TODO should add all the notes at once
```

instead of one by one (each add triggers a UI refresh)

```
UserData.addNote(UserData.Note.from(noteData))
                }
            },
            { error -> Log.e(TAG, "Query failure", error) }
    )
}
fun createNote(note : UserData.Note) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating notes")

    Amplify.API.mutate(
            ModelMutation.create(note.data),
            { response ->
                Log.i(TAG, "Created")
                if (response.hasErrors()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, response.errors.first().message)
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Created Note with id: " + 
response.data.id)
                }
            },
            { error -> Log.e(TAG, "Create failed", error) }
    )
}

fun deleteNote(note : UserData.Note?) {

    if (note == null) return

    Log.i(TAG, "Deleting note $note")

    Amplify.API.mutate(
            ModelMutation.delete(note.data),
            { response ->
                Log.i(TAG, "Deleted")
                if (response.hasErrors()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, response.errors.first().message)
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Deleted Note $response")
                }
            },
            { error -> Log.e(TAG, "Delete failed", error) }
    )
}
fun storeImage(filePath: String, key: String){
    val file = File(filePath)
    val options = StorageUploadFileOptions.builder()
        .accessLevel(StorageAccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        .build()
    Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
        key,
        file,
        options,
        { progress -> Log.i(TAG, "Fraction 
completed:${progress.fractionCompleted}") },
        { result -> Log.i(TAG, "Successfully uploaded: " + 
result.key) },
        { error -> Log.e(TAG, "Upload failed", error) }
    )
}

fun deleteImage(key : String) {

    val options = StorageRemoveOptions.builder()
        .accessLevel(StorageAccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        .build()

    Amplify.Storage.remove(
        key,
        options,
        { result -> Log.i(TAG, "Successfully removed: " + 
result.key) },
        { error -> Log.e(TAG, "Remove failure", error) }
    )
}

fun retrieveImage(key: String, completed : (image: Bitmap) -> 
Unit) {
    val options = StorageDownloadFileOptions.builder()
        .accessLevel(StorageAccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        .build()

    val file = File.createTempFile("image", ".image")

    Amplify.Storage.downloadFile(
        key,
        file,
        options,
        { progress -> Log.i(TAG, "Fraction completed: 
${progress.fractionCompleted}") },
        { result ->
            Log.i(TAG, "Successfully downloaded: 
${result.file.name}")
            val imageStream = FileInputStream(file)
            val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
            completed(image)
        },
        { error -> Log.e(TAG, "Download Failure", error) }
    )
}

}
```

Comment: The error is given in the queryNotes() function. It says Null Poiniter exception there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your code before posting it, the indentation seems messed up and it's pretty hard to read. You can surround the code with \`\`\` lines (before and after) instead of relying on 4-space indent, so you don't have this kind of broken formatting. Also, if you add `kotlin` after the ``` in the leading line (like ```kotlin) it will add syntax coloring.

Comment: Also it would help to provide the actual stacktrace you're getting (possibly truncated if too long), so people can immediately see where the problem is.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?